# How to create list of f-string (alike) based on pd.DataFrame values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, f-string

**Problem**
How to create a list of strings with placeholders (i.e., "f-string"-like) based on values of a pandas DataFrame?

**Example**

Imagine I have following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['Alice', 13, 'apples'],
    ['Bob', 17, 'bananas']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=['name', 'qty', 'fruit']
)
```

How to create a list of strings using something like `f"{name} ate {qty} {fruit}"` as a pattern?
In other words, how to create following list:

```
[
    'Alice ate 13 apples',
    'Bob ate 17 bananas'
]
```

Comment: You mean `(df.name+' ate '+df.qty.astype(str)+' '+df.fruit).tolist()` ?

Comment: @anky_91 Yes, you are right. I also think that your answer is better than the others provided, as it avoids a for-loop, and is more (imho) pythonic. Would you mind transforming your comment as an answer?

Comment: Okay, i added it.

Comment: @ebosi Sorry, but why in accepting answer is no f string? Because your question clearly state need f strings for solution, no need any solution with expected output.

Comment: @jezrael you are right: with the initial phrasing of my question (i.e. at the time you wrote your answer and, later, your comment), the accepted answer wasn't answering _the question_ itself, but rather _the issue I was facing_. I believe that anky_91's answer is more "pythonic", as it's a one-liner without a for-loop… and thus, more appropriate as "accepted answer". I've appreciated your answer, though. But I understand you could be frustrated as I've realized I was facing a XY problem only after you spent time helping me.

Comment: @ebosi Ya, exactly. unfortunately it means answer is closed as dupe.

Comment: @jezrael even better! thanks for the tidy up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this to an answer, we can combine the columns and call `.tolist()` at the end:

```
(df.name+' ate '+df.qty.astype(str)+' '+df.fruit).tolist()
```

**Output:**

```
['Alice ate 13 apples', 'Bob ate 17 bananas']
```

Answer (score 6):

Use list comprehension with list of dicts by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
a = [f"{x['name']} ate {x['qty']} {x['fruit']}" for x in df.to_dict('r')]
print (a)
['Alice ate 13 apples', 'Bob ate 17 bananas']
```

Or:

```
a = [f"{name} ate {qty} {fruit}" for name, qty, fruit in df[['name','qty','fruit']].values]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

[pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['name'] + " ate " + str(x['qty']) + " " + x['fruit'],1).values
```